# How can a Java client use the native Windows-MY store to provide its client certificate as required during a SSL handshake?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl

This question was also posted at [TLS client authentication fails when using SunMSCAPI](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10498197&#10498197) but has not found an answer.

I have a Java6 application running on a Windows Win2008R2 client that connects to a server requiring client certificates.  The Java application is required to use the native Windows stores, i.e. Windows-Root and Windows-My, and employs the SunMSCAPI provider.  The Windows certificate management console reports that both the client cert and CA cert that signed it are correct and enabled for all purposes.

Server verification works exactly as expected, but client authentication fails when the client throws a SSLException complaining that the privatekey is not an RSA private key.  However, when the Java default provider is used instead, and the same client certificate is taken from a JKS keystore, i.e. SunMSCAPI and the Windows stores are not used, client authentication works just as expected and the SSL connection succeeds.

When executed, the application reports that it's using the SunMSCAPI provider and is able to print the correct client certificate as well as information about its RSAPrivateKey.   Tracing indicates that the client exception occurs after the servers 'Hello Done' as its response to the server's certificate request is being prepared.

The relevant code bits for the client keystore portion of this are:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
KeyManagerFactory kFac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
Provider pvdr = new sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI();  
Security.insertProviderAt(pvdr,1);
KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY",pvdr);
kStore.load(null,null);
kFac.init(kstore,null);
sslContext.init(kFac.getKeyManagers(), <a trust factory>.getTrustManagers(), new java.security.SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sockFactory = SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket)sockFactory.createSocket(<some destination host>, <some destination port>);
BufferedInputStream bInStr = new BufferedInputStream(sslSock.getInputStream());
bInStr.read(<the read arguments>);   <<< exception thrown in here
```

Any pointers or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace shown in your link shows the problem to be at RSA's JSSL provider.  Especially for this case you should use Sun/Oracle's JSSE provider.  It's the default one anyway.

Call it as

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "SunJSSE");
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Unfortunately, we're required to be FIPS 140-2 and required to use RSA.