# Spring ssl bundle for certificate material from windows certificate stores - server and client certificates

Tags: java, spring, windows, cryptoapi

I've raised this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39809) with spring and received some great guidance on how to extend spring's recently added SSL bundles to accessing the material from the windows cert store. I am looking to lower the cost of maintaining and managing these certificates and storing and fetching them from the windows store is hence advantageous. I already have a solution for CA/trust material - this is specifically about server and client certificates.

I'm looking for any clues on how to implement it - mostly in Java, or JNI. I found some general information here
[Accessing Windows Certificate Store certs via Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166304/accessing-windows-certificate-store-certs-via-java)
but i'm hoping to find some more concrete information before i dive into implementation so i don't take a wrong path

It directs me to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#certificate_and_certificate_store_functions) - which is good, if i know i have to resort to JNI (And [also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-listing-the-certificates-in-a-store)

But before i dive into JNI i wanted to understand more about  java-security-mscapi-provider and how it gets material from either the MY cert store or the ROOT cert store.
I dove into these links, but hit a dead end trying to find where it actually enumerates the cert stores in windows and finds one of those
[Java security - MSCAPI provider: How to use without password popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495392/java-security-mscapi-provider-how-to-use-without-password-popup)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/jdk.crypto.mscapi/windows/classes/sun/security/mscapi/SunMSCAPI.java

Can anyone point me to how mscapi finds and loads information from the MY store ?
Can anyone give me a reason that doing this in Java won't work - and i should just use the C/JNI approach ?

Note we already use a jks in the filesystem, and i can configure bundles as a pem, or a jks - i am specifically interested in the windows store for a lower maintenance option.

Comment: This may provide a way of doing via Java code, not resorting to JNI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832672/how-can-a-java-client-use-the-native-windows-my-store-to-provide-its-client-cert?rq=2

Comment: More possibilities https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239859/how-to-load-next-generation-certificates-from-the-microsoft-keystore-using-java?rq=2

Comment: Well, i've settled on using JNA, this test showing how to enumerate certs https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32Test.java#L462, and this code for loading the material into a keystore, since thats what a bundle exposes https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-java-keystore-programmatically-bill-young. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/managing-certificates-with-certificate-stores looks like it will explain which stores i can fetch them from, and understand the required flags from JNA/CryptoAPI